# Read end of line while looping word by word in c++

Tags: c++

Am reading a file which contains list of sentences , I need to read each word and try to figure out this word in which line number ..
the file contains :

```
I am for truth
no matter who tells it,
I am for justice,
no matter who it is for or against
Malcom X
```

and I want the output to be in this form :

```
against 4 
matter 4
am 1, 3 
no 2, 4
for 1, 3, 4 
or 4
I 1, 3 
tells 2
is 4 
truth 1
it 2, 4 
who 2,4
justice 3 
X 5
Malcolm 5
```

am using binary search trees and here is my code :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fstream infile ;
    BSTFCI <string>* bst = new BSTFCI<string>();
    string word;
    string line;
    infile.open("test.txt" , ios::in);
    if(infile.fail())
    {
      cout<<"Error Opening file"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }

    while(!infile.eof())
    {

        infile>>word;

        for(int i=0 ; i<word.size();i++)
        {
            if(ispunct(word[i]))
            word.erase(i,1);        
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
        if(!bst->search(word))
        {
          cout<<word<<endl;
          bst->insert(word);
          cout<<"add"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
         cout<<word<<endl;
         cout<<"exist"<<endl;
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, read the file a line at a time, so you can keep count of the lines. Read each line a word at a line so you can keep track of the words. Choose a suitable data structure to store the information. Output all the information when you are done.

Comment: Well now I can see the code you are failing on the first piece of my advice. There's nothing in the above code that tells you which line a word is on. Nor is there anything in your data structure to store line numbers.

Comment: I will use a vector to store line numbers but I don't know how to count them while am looping on the file word by word ?

Comment: As I said, read the file line by line. Read each line word by word. Read the file with getline, put each line into a istringstream, then read each word from the istringstream.

Comment: could you tell me how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might get you started,

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

// read the file line by line
int line_number = 0;
string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    ++line_number;
    // put the line in an istringstream
    istringstream buffer(line);
    // read the words from the line
    string word;
    while (buffer >> word)
    {
        // do something with word and line_number
        // save them in some data structure
    }
}
```